# Convert ant signJar task to gradle

Tags: gradle, build, ant, sign

I'm converting an ant build script to gradle. As part of the ant steps the .jar file being created is signed. The ant sign target looks like:

```
<signjar alias="${keystore.alias}" keystore="${keystore.file}" storepass="${keystore.password}" >
        <path>
            <fileset dir="${build.jars.dir}" includes="xxx-1.0-SNAP.jar"/>
        </path>
</signjar>
```

In my gradle build I have

```
apply plugin 'signing'

...
task signJar(type: SignJar, dependsOn: reobfJar) {
    keyStore = 'certs/keystore.jks'
    alias = 'somealias'
    storePass = 'somepassword'
    keyPass = 'somepassword'
    inputFile = 'build/libs/xxx-1.0-SNAP.jar'            <<< these lines
    outputFile = 'build/libs/xxx-1.0-SNAP_signed.jar'    <<< give error
}
```

build.dependsOn signJar

The error message for the inputFile and outputFile lines is "Cannot assign string to Class < InputFile > ". I can't figure out how to correctly make this assignment. (As you may have guessed I'm not a gradle expert). How do I make the assigment of the jar I'm building to inputFile and the new jar name I want to output file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. Here's the task that I was able to put in my build.gradle file. It doesn't require any new plugin (I'm currently using the 'java' plugin, but I don't know if this task depends upon that.)

Although this shows specific settings and paths for my build envt, I think its easy enough to modify for your needs.

```
task signJar <<{

        def signdir  = new File("$buildDir/jars/signed")
        signdir.mkdirs()

        ant.signjar(
                destDir: "${signdir.absolutePath}",
                jar: 'build/libs/*.jar',
                alias:'somealias',
                storetype:"jks",
                keystore:"certs/keystore.jks",
                storepass:'somepassword',
                verbose:true,
                preservelastmodified:"true"
        )

}

build.dependsOn signJar
```

Comment: So there is no way in doing it without the `ant.signjar` command purely in Groovy leaving the ANT dependecy aside?

Comment: @ThomasS. You could write a gradle task or custom plugin to build an OS call to `jarsigner` which is what the Ant signjar task uses behind the scenes anyway.